# Unity: Set LightProbes to "Off" on Static objects

Tags: unity, lightprobes

Since I use Light Probes for Indoor Scenes only I only need them to work on Dynamic Objects. Objects in Indoor Scenes are all Lightmap Static and baked, objects in outdoor scenes rely on real time lighting.

Most objects are not within range but sometimes the Lightprobes from inside interfere with Static objects outside and add light to them that should not be. It's really time consuming to disable LightProbes in every individual Mesh Renderer

[image: y d]

I sort all Prefabs & Game Objects by Static, LightmapStatic and Dynamic. Turning Lightmapping on and off can be easily done in the hiearchy but turning off LightProbes needs to be done in every individual Mesh Renderer. Is that so, or am I overlooking something? If not this is really something that should get fixed.

My Version is 2017.3.1f1

[image]